# How to set gaps for ALL Components in the GridBagLayout?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, layout, gridbaglayout

When you are using group layout you set all the gaps with:

```
setAutoCreateGaps(true);
setAutoCreateContainerGaps(true);
```

Is there a same function for `GridBagLayout`?

Comment: you may want to take a look at the `insets`property of the GridBagConstraints

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- [Setting Gap Sizes in a GridBadLayout](http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.awt/gridbag_Gap.html)
- [good description](http://www.formdev.com/jformdesigner/doc/layouts/gridbaglayout/)
- use [EmptyBorders](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/border/EmptyBorder.html)
- use invisible `JComponents`

Comment: One of the links is no longer valid I'm afraid.

Answer (score 5):

In GridBagLayout, using GridBagConstraints you can set gaps with the below properties;

1. GridBagConstraints.ipadx,GridBagConstraints.ipady:
   Specifies the component's internal padding within the layout.
2. GridBagConstraints.insets:
   Specifies the component's external padding.
3. GridBagConstraints.weightx,GridBagConstraints.weighty:
   Used to determine how to distribute space.

For Example:

```
pane.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
c.ipady = 40;      //make this component tall
c.ipadx = 10;      //make this component wide
c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.PAGE_END; //bottom of space
c.insets = new Insets(10,0,0,0);  //top padding
c.gridx = 1;       //first column
c.gridy = 2;       //third row
c.gridwidth = 2;   //2 columns wide
c.weightx = 0.5;   //increase horizontal space
c.weighty = 1.0;   //increase vertical space
```